# using double buffering kinda ruin my applet. and it has java uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: java, applet, awt, custom-component, event-dispatch-thread

this is my code actually it's just a moving space invader game.
i search the internet for the animation
i have tried the double buffering, it gets rid the flickering but its ruining the entire output. it also has java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. this is so hard...

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SpaceInvaders extends Applet implements Runnable{


AudioClip soundFile1; 
int Xposition=500,Xposition1=-500,Yposition=15;
Thread runner;

public void start()
{
if (runner == null);
{
runner = new Thread(this);
runner.start();
}
}

public void stop()
{
if (runner != null);
{
runner.stop();
runner = null;

}
}

public void run()
{
while(true)
{
setBackground(Color.black);
repaint();
try {Thread.sleep(20);}
catch(InterruptedException e) { }
}
}

public void init() 
{ 
soundFile1 = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(),"si.au"); 
//soundFile1.play(); 
soundFile1.loop();
}   
public void paint( Graphics g ) {   
  g.setColor( Color.orange );
  g.fillRect(Xposition+50,10,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+60,10,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+40,20,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+50,20,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+60,20,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+70,20,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+30,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+40,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+50,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+60,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+70,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+80,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+20,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+30,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+50,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+60,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+80,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+90,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+20,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+30,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+40,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+50,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+60,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+70,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+80,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+90,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+40,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+70,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+30,70,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+50,70,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+60,70,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+80,70,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+20,80,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+40,80,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+70,80,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+90,80,10,10);

  g.setColor(Color.red);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+140,10,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+200,10,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+120,20,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+150,20,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+190,20,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+220,20,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+120,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+140,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+150,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+160,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+170,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+180,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+190,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+200,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+220,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+120,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+130,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+140,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+160,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+170,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+180,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+200,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+210,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+220,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+120,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+130,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+140,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+150,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+160,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+170,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+180,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+190,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+200,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+210,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+220,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+130,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+140,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+150,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+160,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+170,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+180,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+190,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+200,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+210,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+140,70,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+200,70,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+130,80,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+210,80,10,10);



  g.setColor(Color.blue);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+280,10,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+290,10,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+270,20,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+280,20,10,10);           
  g.fillRect(Xposition+290,20,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+300,20,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+260,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+270,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+280,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+290,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+300,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+310,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+250,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+260,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+280,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+290,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+310,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+320,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+250,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+260,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+270,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+280,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+290,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+300,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+310,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+320,50,10,10);               //20=250 30=260 40=270 50=280 60=290 70=300 80=310 90=320
  g.fillRect(Xposition+260,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+280,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+290,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+310,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+250,70,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+320,70,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+260,80,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+310,80,10,10);


  g.setColor(Color.yellow);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+370,10,10,10);           
  g.fillRect(Xposition+430,10,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+380,20,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+420,20,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+370,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+380,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+390,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+400,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+410,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+420,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+430,30,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+360,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+370,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+390,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+400,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+410,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+430,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+440,40,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+350,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+360,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+370,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+380,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+390,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+400,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+410,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+420,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+430,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+440,50,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+450,50,10,10);       //120=350 130=360 140=370 150=380 160=390 170=400 180=410 190=420 200=430 210=440 220=450
  g.fillRect(Xposition+350,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+370,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+380,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+390,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+400,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+410,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+420,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+430,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+450,60,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+350,70,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+370,70,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+430,70,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+450,70,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+380,80,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+390,80,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+410,80,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition+420,80,10,10);


   Xposition--;
     if (Xposition < -500)
  {
Xposition = 500;
}

 g.setColor(Color.green);
 g.fillRect(Xposition1+230,130,10,10);
 g.fillRect(Xposition1+240,130,10,10);
 g.fillRect(Xposition1+250,130,10,10);
 g.fillRect(Xposition1+260,130,10,10);
 g.fillRect(Xposition1+270,130,10,10);
 g.fillRect(Xposition1+280,130,10,10);  
 g.fillRect(Xposition1+210,140,10,10);
 g.fillRect(Xposition1+220,140,10,10);
 g.fillRect(Xposition1+230,140,10,10);
 g.fillRect(Xposition1+240,140,10,10);
   g.fillRect(Xposition1+250,140,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition1+260,140,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition1+270,140,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition1+280,140,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition1+290,140,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition1+300,140,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition1+200,150,10,10);
 g.fillRect(Xposition1+210,150,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition1+220,150,10,10);
 g.fillRect(Xposition1+230,150,10,10);
  g.fillRect(Xposition1+240,150,10,10);
   g.fillRect(Xposition1+250,150,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+260,150,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+270,150,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+280,150,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+290,150,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+300,150,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+310,150,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+190,160,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+200,160,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+220,160,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+230,160,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+250,160,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+260,160,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+280,160,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+290,160,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+310,160,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+320,160,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+180,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+190,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+200,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+210,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+220,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+230,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+240,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+250,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+260,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+270,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+280,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+290,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+300,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+310,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+320,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+330,170,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+200,180,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+210,180,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+220,180,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+250,180,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+260,180,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+290,180,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+300,180,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+310,180,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+210,190,10,10);
g.fillRect(Xposition1+300,190,10,10);


Xposition1++;
if (Xposition1 > 500)
{
    Xposition1 = -500;
}

Yposition--;
if (Yposition > 500)
{
    Yposition = -500;
}

g.setColor(Color.magenta);
g.fillRect(260,Yposition+240,10,10);
g.fillRect(260,Yposition+250,10,10);

g.setColor(Color.white);

g.fillRect(260,310,10,10);
g.fillRect(250,320,10,10);
g.fillRect(260,320,10,10);
g.fillRect(270,320,10,10);
g.fillRect(250,330,10,10);
g.fillRect(260,330,10,10);
g.fillRect(270,330,10,10);
g.fillRect(200,340,10,10);
g.fillRect(210,340,10,10);
g.fillRect(220,340,10,10);
g.fillRect(230,340,10,10);
g.fillRect(240,340,10,10);
g.fillRect(250,340,10,10);
g.fillRect(260,340,10,10);
g.fillRect(270,340,10,10);
g.fillRect(280,340,10,10);
g.fillRect(290,340,10,10);
g.fillRect(300,340,10,10);
g.fillRect(310,340,10,10);
g.fillRect(320,340,10,10);
g.fillRect(190,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(200,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(210,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(220,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(230,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(240,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(250,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(260,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(270,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(280,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(290,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(300,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(310,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(320,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(330,350,10,10);
g.fillRect(190,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(200,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(210,360,10,10);
 g.fillRect(220,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(230,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(240,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(250,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(260,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(270,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(280,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(290,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(300,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(310,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(320,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(330,360,10,10);
g.fillRect(190,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(200,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(210,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(220,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(230,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(240,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(250,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(260,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(270,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(280,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(290,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(300,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(310,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(320,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(330,370,10,10);
g.fillRect(190,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(200,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(210,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(220,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(230,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(240,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(250,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(260,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(270,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(280,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(290,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(300,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(310,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(320,380,10,10);
g.fillRect(330,380,10,10);




}
public static void main(String[] args)
{

 }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an applet? There's no reason to be doing so in this day and age.

Comment: uhm it's one of our project because i'm a student

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't do this.

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        setBackground(Color.black);
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

While I appricate that this is being run from inside a `Runnable` context, you are effecting the UI from outside the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), which is NEVER a good idea.

You're better of using a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), see [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more info.

Second of all.  There is nothing double buffered about your sample code.

Double buffering would have you using an off-screen buffered (such as a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)) to draw the contents of the screen to before it's rendered to the screen.

Thridly, if you don't want to implement your own double buffering solution, I would use a `JPanel` or `JComponent` and add them to a `JAppelt`.  `JComponent` (and it's children) support double buffering by default (you shouldn't paint directly to a top level container, there's to much icky stuff going on under the hood you don't want to have to become responsible for).

Fourthly, I would take some serious time to read through the [Graphics 2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) tutorial.

**UPDATE**

Here's my take on the basic idea.  Note, I've not added the player, you can figure that out.

```
public class SpaceFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
                new SpaceFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public SpaceFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new SpacePane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected class SpacePane extends JPanel implements Screen {

        private BufferedImage buffer;

        public SpacePane() {
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            // We need to make that the screen pane is actually on the screen...
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new UpdaterThread(SpacePane.this));
                    thread.setDaemon(true);
                    thread.start();

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (buffer != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void renderBuffer(final BufferedImage image) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    buffer = image;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    protected interface Screen {
        public Dimension getSize();
        public void renderBuffer(final BufferedImage image);
    }

    protected class UpdaterThread implements Runnable {

        private int cycle = 0;
        private BufferedImage[] buffers = new BufferedImage[2];
        private Screen screen;
        // A row of aliens...
        private RowOfAliens rowOfAliens;
        // Adjusts the speed at which the aliens move
        private int speed = 10;

        public UpdaterThread(Screen screen) {
            this.screen = screen;
        }

        public Screen getScreen() {
            return screen;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // We're only using 1 row...
            rowOfAliens = new RowOfAliens();
            rowOfAliens.setLocation(new Point(0, 0));
            rowOfAliens.setDirection(10);

            while (true) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(16); // 60 fps
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }

                cycle++;

                // Update the offscreen buffer...
                BufferedImage buffer = getBuffer();
                if (buffer != null) {

                    // Move the alients...
                    updateAliens();

                    // Paint the various layers
                    int width = buffer.getWidth();
                    int height = buffer.getHeight();
                    Graphics2D g2d = buffer.createGraphics();
                    // You could paint a space scape here
                    paintBackground(g2d, width, height);
                    // The aliens and other game arifcates
                    paintMidground(g2d, width, height);
                    // Special effects
                    paintForeground(g2d, width, height);
                    g2d.dispose();

                    // Send the buffer to the screen
                    paintBuffer(buffer);

                }

            }

        }

        protected void updateAliens() {
            Screen screen = getScreen();
            if (screen != null) {

                // Controls the speed at which the aliens move
                if (cycle % speed == 0) {
                    // Get the aliens current location and direction...
                    Point p = rowOfAliens.getLocation();
                    p.x += rowOfAliens.getDirection();

                    int screenWidth = screen.getSize().width;
                    int screenHeight = screen.getSize().height;
                    // Boundray check...
                    if (p.x + rowOfAliens.getBounds().width > screenWidth) {
                        p.x = screenWidth - rowOfAliens.getBounds().width;
                        // Reverse direction
                        rowOfAliens.setDirection(-10);
                        p.y += 10;
                    } else if (p.x < 0) {
                        p.x = 0;
                        p.y += 10;
                        // Reverse direction
                        rowOfAliens.setDirection(10);
                    }
                    // Set the location of the row...
                    rowOfAliens.setLocation(p);

                }

            }

        }

        protected void paintBackground(Graphics2D g2d, int width, int height) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        }

        protected void paintMidground(Graphics2D g2d, int width, int height) {
            Point p = rowOfAliens.getLocation();
            g2d.translate(p.x, p.y);
            rowOfAliens.paint(g2d);
            g2d.translate(-p.x, -p.y);
        }

        protected void paintForeground(Graphics2D g2d, int width, int height) {
        }

        protected BufferedImage getBuffer() {
            BufferedImage buffer = null;

            Screen screen = getScreen();
            if (screen != null) {
                // Determine which buffer to use
                int index = 0;
                if (cycle % 2 != 0) {
                    index = 1;
                }

                buffer = buffers[index];
                if (buffer == null || buffer.getWidth() != screen.getSize().width || buffer.getHeight() != screen.getSize().height) {
                    // Create a compataible graphics object, so it will render faster on the screen...
                    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                    GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
                    GraphicsConfiguration gc = gs.getDefaultConfiguration();

                    buffer = gc.createCompatibleImage(screen.getSize().width, screen.getSize().height, Transparency.OPAQUE);
                    buffers[index] = buffer;
                }

            }

            return buffer;

        }

        protected void paintBuffer(BufferedImage buffer) {
            // Send the buffer to the screen...
            Screen screen = getScreen();
            if (screen != null) {
                screen.renderBuffer(buffer);
            }
        }
    }

    protected class RowOfAliens {

        private List<Alien> lstAliens;
        private Point location;
        private int direction;
        private Rectangle bounds;

        public RowOfAliens() {
            lstAliens = new ArrayList<Alien>(25);
            lstAliens.add(new AlienType1());
            lstAliens.add(new AlienType2());
            lstAliens.add(new AlienType3());
            lstAliens.add(new AlienType4());

            setLocation(new Point(0, 0));
            // Calculate the size of the row...
            bounds = new Rectangle(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0, 0);

            int index = 0;
            for (Alien alien : lstAliens) {

                Rectangle aBounds = alien.getBounds();
                aBounds.setLocation(alien.getLocation());
                System.out.println(index + ": " + aBounds);

                bounds.x = Math.min(bounds.x, aBounds.x);
                bounds.y = Math.min(bounds.y, aBounds.y);

                bounds.width = Math.max(bounds.width, aBounds.x + aBounds.width);
                bounds.height = Math.max(bounds.height, aBounds.y + aBounds.height);

            }

            System.out.println(bounds);

        }

        protected void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            // Paint the aliens
            Point pos = getLocation();

            for (Alien alien : lstAliens) {
                g2d.setColor(alien.getColor());
                Point p = alien.getLocation();
                // We need to take into account the current location of the row
                // in relation to the alien...
                int xPos = p.x - pos.x;
                g2d.translate(xPos, 0);
                g2d.fill(alien);
                g2d.translate(-xPos, 0);
            }

        }

        protected void layoutRow() {
            // Layout the aliens within there row based on the currrent location...
            // Techniqually, we could offset the aliens at 0x0 and simply adjust the
            // the x position by the width of each alien and it's gap
            // This would eliminate the need to adjust the position in the
            // paint method, but hay...
            Point p = new Point(getLocation());
            for (Alien alien : lstAliens) {
                alien.setLocation(p);
                p = new Point(p.x, p.y);
                p.x += alien.getBounds().width + 10;
            }

        }

        public Rectangle getBounds() {
            return bounds;
        }

        public void setLocation(Point point) {
            if (location == null || point == null || (!location.equals(point))) {
                location = point;
                layoutRow();
            }
        }

        public Point getLocation() {
            return new Point(location);
        }

        public void setDirection(int value) {
            direction = value;
        }

        public int getDirection() {
            return direction;
        }
    }

    protected abstract class Alien extends Path2D.Float {

        private Point location;
        private Color color;

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public void setLocation(Point location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public Point getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public void addRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            moveTo(x, y);
            lineTo(x + width, y);
            lineTo(x + width, y + height);
            lineTo(x, y + height);
            lineTo(x, y);
        }
    }

    protected class AlienType1 extends Alien {

        public AlienType1() {
            setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            addRectangle(30, 0, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 0, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(10, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(0, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(10, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(0, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(10, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(10, 60, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 60, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 60, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 60, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(0, 70, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 70, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 70, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 70, 10, 10);
            closePath();
        }
    }

    protected class AlienType2 extends Alien {

        public AlienType2() {
            setColor(Color.RED);
            addRectangle(20, 0, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 0, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(0, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(100, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(0, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(100, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(0, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(10, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(90, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(100, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(0, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(10, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(90, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(100, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(10, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(90, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 60, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 60, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(10, 70, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(90, 70, 10, 10);
            closePath();
        }
    }

    protected class AlienType3 extends Alien {

        public AlienType3() {
            setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            addRectangle(20, 0, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 0, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 0, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(10, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(90, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(0, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(10, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(90, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(100, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(0, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(100, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(0, 60, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 60, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 60, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(100, 60, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 70, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 70, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 70, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 70, 10, 10);
            closePath();
        }
    }

    protected class AlienType4 extends Alien {

        public AlienType4() {
            setColor(Color.GREEN);
            addRectangle(50, 0, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 0, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 0, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 0, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(90, 0, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(100, 0, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(90, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(100, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(110, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(120, 10, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(90, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(100, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(110, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(120, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(130, 20, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(10, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(100, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(110, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(130, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(140, 30, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(0, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(10, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(50, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(60, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(90, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(100, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(110, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(120, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(130, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(140, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(150, 40, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(20, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(40, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(70, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(80, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(110, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(120, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(130, 50, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(30, 60, 10, 10);
            addRectangle(120, 60, 10, 10);
            closePath();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace the frame reference with your appetite and add the SpacePane to it

Comment: *"i really need an applet.."*  You'll probably find the user really needs a free floating game launched from a link (that would be a `JFrame` launched using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)).  Having space invaders invade a hole in a web page seems ..odd.  Also, applets are a lot harder to develop and maintain.

Comment: so can i still use applet instead of JFrame?

Comment: Yes. Applet and JFrame both inherit from Container. You simply just need to add your game panel (SpacePane in my example) to what ever top level container you want, that's the power of the design

Comment: i'm just a beginner in java programming and all i want is an applet with animation, not a game. sorry if i didn't told you this.

Comment: That's fine, you can simply the example a little, not needing things like collision detection and the like, but the basics still hold true

Comment: how am i suppose to convert it to an applet? and by the way your classes and methods you use is to complicated and i didn't know them for know because i didn't studied it yet.

Comment: 1. Create a JAppet as per normal. In the init method, set the layout to BorderLayout and call add(new SpacePane()). 2. You're trying to achieve 3 of the most complex tasks I can think of, game programming, custom graphics & animation. My example is actually relative simple, given the fact that there are no special effects, collision detection or player controls & it's only dealing with a single row of aliens, if you're having trouble with it, then this project might be beyond you at this time and you need to do some more study before you come back to it

Comment: can i still use my codes, remove one of the code that i must not do and use your space pane?

Comment: E:\edward1\SpaceInvaders.java:19: error: modifier protected not allowed here
   protected class SpacePane extends JPanel implements Screen {
E:\edward1\SpaceInvaders.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
   protected class SpacePane extends JPanel implements Screen {
  symbol: class Screen
E:\edward1\SpaceInvaders.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new UpdaterThread(SpacePane.this));
  symbol: class UpdaterThread
E:\edward1\SpaceInvaders.java:55: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override

Comment: If SpacePane is in its own file, make it public, not protected